# How to Destroy Text after certain Time

Tags: unity, text

So, I have this 2D game built. In it, a text pop ups in the beginning but I want that text to stop appearing after certain seconds. 
(Using Unity)*This text is also attached to a panel*

Comment: Why would destroying/hiding text need to be any different from destroying/hiding any other game object? Did you try using [the Destroy() method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way would be to use a script which uses the [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) method with a time-parameter on the the text panel when it is created. This is an example of a simple self-destruct script you can attach to any game object which is supposed to have a limited lifetime:

```
public class SelfDestruct :  MonoBehaviour {
    public float lifetime = 3.0;
    public void Start() {
        Destroy(this.gameObject, lifetime);
    }
}
```

An even nicer method might be to not have it disappear suddenly but rather fade it out by lowering its alpha value and then destroy it when the alpha reaches zero. Here is a simplified version of a "fade out and destroy" script from one of my projects (supposed to get attached to a panel which can have as many sub-components as you want):

```
public class FadeOutAndDestroy : MonoBehaviour {

    public float stayTime = 3.0f;
    public float fadeoutTime = 1.0f;

    private float time;

    public void Start() {
        time = stayTime + fadeoutTime;
    }

    void Update () {
        time -= Time.deltaTime;        

        if (time < fadeoutTime && time > 0) {
            float alpha  = time / fadeoutTime;
            foreach (CanvasRenderer r in GetComponentsInChildren<CanvasRenderer>()) {
                r.SetAlpha(alpha);
            }              
        }

        if (time <= 0) {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Another thing I want to ask is a bit simple one. But, How do you call an object of Editor in script .

Comment: Please accept the answer and open a new question (or better yet do some research).

Comment: @SabinPyakurel I do not fully understand what you mean, but this appears to be a new question unrelated to this one. So please post it as a new question. If this answer answers the question you posted above, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark-icon next to it.